# OpenShift 3 Webapp With Access to File System

Tags: filesystems, openshift, storage, persistent

I have a **Tomcat 8** web app running on **OpenShift 3**.

I want to be able to **read** and **write** files on 'the file system'.

I have been wading through documentation and looking for examples of how to achieve this.

I see that there are many types of persistent storage, for example **NFS**, **EBS**, **GlusterFS** etc.

So, my first question is.

**What is the best file system to use for simple read/write access to text based xml files?**

Preferably like a *nix file system.

Any example would be much appreciated...

Comment: Just for clarity - you're using OpenShift Origin or OpenShift Container Platform? OpenShift Online only includes EBS and emtpyDir.

Comment: I have a free developer account, it's OpenShift 3. In About it says OpenShift Master: v3.6.173.0.7 (online version 3.5.1.79). Does that mean I have to use EBS?

Comment: Correct, you will have to use EBS. You can find more information about the specific implementations of persistent storage for OpenShift Online in the documentation, https://docs.openshift.com/online/architecture/additional_concepts/storage.html#pv-restrictions.

Comment: So that means that with the starter setup, it is impossible to implement an application that needs to >>> write to a file more than once <<<. So my simple webapp that reads and writes to an xml database is NOT possible...

Answer (score 0):

The free **OpenShift 3 Starter** service ONLY allows 'filesystem storage' to **EBS** (Amazon Elastic Block Storage). Which can only be written to ONCE.

To get access to **GlusterFS** of **NFS** you have to go to the paid service which starts at **$50** per month. They are the only filesystems that allow multiple writes to a file.

Comment: Your wording here is confusing. What the ``ONCE`` bit means in ``RWO`` for the file system type is that the persistent volume can only be mounted on one node in the cluster at a time. This means the persistent volume can't be used with a scaled application and can't using rolling deployment strategy, but must use recreate. You can still write to the persistent volume as many times as you want. Also, unless has changed recently, my understanding is that EBS is still the only storage type available.

Comment: I want to be able to write an xml file and then rewrite that same file with data when it changes ('xml database' if you like). Graham, are you saying that is possible? Because when I have used Amazon S3 in the past a file could only be written once. To do what I want, you would have to delete the original file and then write it again.

Comment: Persistent volumes in OpenShift 3 on Amazon and going to be Elastic Block Storage (EBS), not S3. S3 is not use for filesystem type storage, but application level storage through an API. You are confusing two different Amazon products.

Comment: So, are you saying Graham, that I could implement my little xml 'database' (rewritable files) using EBS? Is there an example of this approach anywhere. I haven't found one and I have been looking for ages...

Comment: Ignore that it is EBS. It is mounted as a normal file system as far as your application is concerned. If you can use normal file system operations to write your database to the file system, that is what you use. You just need to do it in the file system directory where the volume is mounted. There is nothing special. EBS is not a application level API protocol like S3 is.

Comment: Thanks Graham, I will try this at some point. I have now used up my precious resources on the starter to work out the postgresql database connection. You help is much appreciated...